# Will setting the processor affinity for Pyrit improve the rate at which it cracks a wireless key?

Tags: linux, passwords, wpa2-psk

I have an Alienware i7 with Kali linux, and using Pyrit could try about 2000 keys/second.
I configured the GPU (nVidia 9700) and that increased the rate to between 3k and 8k keys/second, but I feel that is still really slow.

If I alter the process affinity and assign 2 or 3 cores to one task, will this improve the rate at which keys are tested?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking...

Comment: Consider getting an AMD/ATI graphics card. They're typically much faster than nVidia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Most likely no.

Processor affinity will only **restrict** programs from using the non-selected cores, so that program will only recieve less timeslices than it could possibly get on multiple cores.

Furthermore, taking a quick glance on [pyrit](https://code.google.com/p/pyrit/) shows performance metrics along with different **graphics card** models. This tells me that pyrit's performance is bound by the graphics card's performance - not CPU performance.

But with all things in close-to-the-metal performance, **test it**. For example, forcing a process to use only one core could possibly reduce cache issues.